# How to load dynamic data using node package "ng-multiselect-dropdown"

Tags: angular, angular6

In Angular(6) project, I am using a node package named **ng-multiselect-dropdown** for a dropdown input field. I am facing difficulty
to load dynamic data in a dropdown list. Is there any way to load dynamic data while using ng-multiselect-dropdown or Is there any
similar node package which provided the same functionality of ng-multiselect-dropdown.

Thank you.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [data]="userDropdownList" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>


 userDropdownList = [];
 ngOnInit() {
 this.departmentService.getUsers(this.authService.getUser().client_id)
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    for (let data of response.data) {
      this.userDropdownList.push({ '_id': data._id,
         'name': data.firstname + ' ' + data.lastname })
    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log("error :", error);
  })
}
```

Comment: What’s the issue, is service working fine ?

Comment: Service is working fine. The data I am getting from the HTTP request is not showing in dropdown list.

Comment: If I declare static array of object like below code, then it works. But from http request , it is not working:                                                                                             this.userDropdownList = [
      { _id: "5ae89f362c6f957fe0ddf173", name: "Raja Khan" },
      { _id: "5ae96638dbceb53af3344d1b", name: "Ubaid Showkat" },
      { _id: "5afd5ec12e275b636bbda827", name: "Keninteiten Daz" },
      { _id: "5b2b752ddd444f78c3f775c5", name: "Calvin Shehryar" },
      { _id: "5b2c993116e48626a589ab70", name: "test s" }
    ];

Comment: code looks fine, did you try declaring the same static thing inside `.subscribe((response: any) => {` ?

Comment: Yes. I declared the same variable.

Comment: I think the library don't have that feature now. check this issue (https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues/5).

Answer (score 4):

Push won't work ,please read the hoe change detection work in angular,
push do not create new reference ,so angular change detection do not detect it hence it won't work

```
this.users.push({item_id:1,item_text:"test"})
```

the above code won't work,so you can do this

```
this.users = this.users.concat({item_id:1,item_text:"test"})
```

or

```
this.tempUsers.push({item_id:1,item_text:"test"})

this.users = this.tempUsers
```